# Image on hover weird margins

Tags: html, css, image

I have a grid of images that display the name on hover. They work fine but on hover there are small margins appearing. In [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fgvuajpL/) that is not happening, but in [codepen](http://codepen.io/leonlaci/pen/rLxbjo) it is happening
HTML:

```
    <section id="portfolio">
      <ul class="grid">
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

But on my end with same code:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is happening in your CodePen and **NOT** in JsFiddle because you are using in your CodePen the normalize.css (the Reset.CSS would have the same effect)

#### Snippet without normalize.css

```css
#portfolio {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
#portfolio .grid {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#portfolio .grid .item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
#portfolio .grid .item-link {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#portfolio .grid .item-link img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#portfolio .grid .item-link .item-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.7);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#portfolio .grid .item-link .item-text {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  top: 40%;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#portfolio .grid .item:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
#portfolio .grid .item:hover .item-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
#portfolio .grid .item:hover .item-text {
  transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .item {
    width: 50% !important;
  }

  .description {
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .item {
    width: 33.33% !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  .item {
    width: 25% !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  .item {
    width: 20% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<section id="portfolio">
      <ul class="grid">
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    </body>
```

#### Snippet with normalize.css

```css
#portfolio {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
#portfolio .grid {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#portfolio .grid .item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
#portfolio .grid .item-link {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#portfolio .grid .item-link img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#portfolio .grid .item-link .item-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.7);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#portfolio .grid .item-link .item-text {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  top: 40%;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#portfolio .grid .item:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
#portfolio .grid .item:hover .item-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
#portfolio .grid .item:hover .item-text {
  transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .item {
    width: 50% !important;
  }

  .description {
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .item {
    width: 33.33% !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  .item {
    width: 25% !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  .item {
    width: 20% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
<section id="portfolio">
      <ul class="grid">
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    </body>
```

Comment: What should I then do? I need the normalize.css

Comment: @LeonLaci I never use normalize.css, but still I find this weird since this happen with reset.css too, a quick fix would be set `margin:1px` to `section`, plus when using `float:left`, dont need to use `inline-block , let me know if you want to include this in my answer

Comment: But the margin of 1px adds a, well a margin. Do I have to put a margin?

Comment: @LeonLaci have you tried at least before commenting?

Comment: By disabling the normalize and adding margin and padding 0 to body I still get the same effect.

Comment: Yes I did try it, it works but add margin to the sides.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add attribute `border="0"` in the img tag like this :

```
 <section id="portfolio">
      <ul class="grid">
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Item" border="0"><span class="item-overlay"></span><span class="item-text">Item</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

Because some browsers like IE shown border to the image by default.

Comment: Doesn't change anything.